# Git merge conflicts, don't want to remove anything

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a merge conflict in a pull request:

```
@import "includes/_variables.scss";
@import "includes/_mixins.scss";
@import "includes/relatedProducts/_styles.scss";
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
@import "includes/stickyHeader/_styles.scss";
>>>>>>> sticky-header
@import "includes/_responsive.scss";
```

and I don't want to remove either of those lines. I want to have them both on master.

What should I do? I want the changes to be seen in pull request and not remove anything, just add the new stuff to already existing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to remove the conflict markers (`<<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>`):

```
@import "includes/_variables.scss";
@import "includes/_mixins.scss";
@import "includes/relatedProducts/_styles.scss";
@import "includes/stickyHeader/_styles.scss";
@import "includes/_responsive.scss";
```

See [Resolving a merge conflict using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/)
 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove these lines from your code:

`<<<<<<< HEAD`

`=======`

and

`>>>>>>> sticky-header`.

Just remember a simple rule while resolving any merge conflicts. What should the final code look like? Make the changes accordingly and proceed. From some of the lines you want to add and some already added lines at the same position, choose/modify the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

> and I don't want to remove either of those lines. I want to have them
>   both on master.
>
> What should I do?

Only remove `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======` and `>>>>>>> sticky-header`, then `git add <file>` and `git commit`

> I want the changes to be seen in pull request and not remove anything
>   Merge

`If you changed the same part of the same file differently in the two branches you’re merging together, Git won’t be able to merge them cleanly.` [git conflict](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merge_conflicts)

If you see conflict, it means the two branches you merging have changed differently the same part of the file you're talking about. Wich means the changes you want to see won't be lost because they are already saved in the commits of these two branches.